# Exception while creating a ProcessEngine with PostgreSQL

Tags: rule-engine, camunda

I’m trying to update the Camunda DMN table programmatically and deploy it again after the update. 
But while creating a process engine, getting the exception for H2 driver, but for my given project I’m using the PostgreSQL database for Camunda tables.

```
ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
                .createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration().buildProcessEngine();


org.camunda.bpm.engine.repository.Deployment deployment = processEngine.getRepositoryService()
                    .createDeployment()
                    .addString(fileName, Dmn.convertToString(dmnModelInstance))
                    .name("Deployment after update").deploy();
```

java.sql.SQLException: Error setting driver on UnpooledDataSource. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.initializeDriver(UnpooledDataSource.java:221)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:200)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:196)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.getConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:93)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.popConnection(PooledDataSource.java:385)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.getConnection(PooledDataSource.java:89)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDatabaseType(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:1300)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create datasource bean explicitly or can declare the datasource attributes in bootstrap.yml or application.properties file.

```
@Configuration
public class ExampleProcessEngineConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
     // Use a JNDI data source or read the properties from
     // env or a properties file.
     // Note: The following shows only a simple data source
     // for In-Memory H2 database.

    SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass(org.h2.Driver.class);
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:camunda;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration() {
    SpringProcessEngineConfiguration config = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();

    config.setDataSource(dataSource());
    config.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());

    config.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("true");
    config.setHistory("audit");
    config.setJobExecutorActivate(true);

    return config;
  }

  @Bean
  public ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngine() {
    ProcessEngineFactoryBean factoryBean = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setProcessEngineConfiguration(processEngineConfiguration());
    return factoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public RepositoryService repositoryService(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
    return processEngine.getRepositoryService();
  }

  @Bean
  public RuntimeService runtimeService(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
    return processEngine.getRuntimeService();
  }

  @Bean
  public TaskService taskService(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
    return processEngine.getTaskService();
  }

  // more engine services and additional beans ...

}
```